# Does Bitnami Neo4j Helm chart values.yaml file supports enabling APOC plugin

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Our team experiments with deploying Neo4j into our Kubernetes environment via Bitnami's Helm Chart.

We rely on [this source](https://github.com/neo4j/helm-charts/blob/dev/neo4j/values.yaml) for our Helm charts.

The Neo4j version that we currently use is: `4.4.19-enterprise`.

[The Documentation](https://neo4j.com/labs/neo4j-helm/1.0.0/tooling/) suggests that starting from Neo4j 4.1, the `APOC core` functions are included with all Neo4j distributions, so I expect our image to contain the configuration to enable it. However there is no clear guide regarding how to enable it as part of a Bitnami's Helm chart, which is a reliable and widely used source.

Comment: Bitnami doesn't seem to have a Neo4j helm chart, can you add a link to it if you have one ?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami doesn't have a chart for Neo4j, so unless you have a link to it I suggest you rephrase your question.

Following the docs https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/kubernetes/plugins/ , you can enable the plugins with the NEO4J_PLUGINS environment variable, it works exactly the same as if you would enable plugins with a vanilla Neo4j container :

Neo4j 5

```yaml
env:
    NEO4J_PLUGINS: '["graph-data-science", "apoc"]'
```

For Neo4j 4

```yaml
env:
    NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS: '["graph-data-science", "apoc"]'
```

Comment: IIRC, the APOC jar still had to be added manually in neo 4 (which OP says they're on), but I could be mistaken?

Comment: No, Neo4j will resolve it from this page https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/versions.json , I suggest this talk to watch https://youtu.be/bTE2Ngcx9vU

Comment: yes indeed! 